# Python - Remove URLs from text with regex

Tags: python, regex, url

I have URLs in a text that look like this:

```
<https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/reportAProblem?p
=22000073760328&o=i>
```

I've used the following pattern to try and remove them:

```
re.sub(r'\<http.+?\>', '', plain, re.S)
```

But it won't get them all, for example, this one doesn't get removed:

```
<http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/email/images_shared/spacer_99999\r\n9.gif>
```

Comment: If you put r (raw string) before assigining the second string (`r'<http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/email/images_shared/spacer_99999\r\n9.gif>'`) or put double backslash (\\\) (`<http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/email/images_shared/spacer_99999\\r\\n9.gif>`) it will work

Comment: This is pretty odd. Played around with it for a bit and it does match it: `re.match(r'.', '\n', re.S)` works, but `re.sub(r'.', '', '\n', re.S)` does not. So it seems to match, but the replacing part fails somehow... really not sure where or how though. It's as if re.S doesn't work for `re.sub`.

Comment: Yeah that's what happens to me. Some URLs are removed but others remain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like this

```
p=re.compile(r'\<http.+?\>', re.DOTALL)
re.sub(p, '', plain)
```

Comment: This did it, thank you. Care to add an explanation as to why the precompiled pattern works?

Comment: Actually after taking a look at the re.sub function I think you missed that there is an additional argument before the flags argument, so something like  `re.sub(r'\<http.+?\>', '', plain, flags=re.S)` should also work.

Comment: @8vius The flag is being passed incorrectly for some reason, although I really don't know why. This encodes the flag in the pattern itself. According to the docs, `re.sub` takes five arguments (pattern, repl, str, count, flags), the last two being optional. However, when I try to call it with 5 arguments, it tells me it expects 4. In Python 3 it works when I do `re.sub(r'.', '', '\n', 0, re.S)`, as well as `re.sub(r'.', '', '\n', flags=re.S)`, neither of which works for me in Python 2, despite what the docs for it say.

Comment: Yes, setting the flags explicitly works as well, thanks. That's why it works with the precompiled then. Thank you both.